# Running Karma on windows "scripts/test.sh: line 9: testacular: command not found"

Tags: node.js, angularjs, karma-runner

I'm trying to do the Angular tutorial on my Windows 7 64-bit PC and I came upon this error when I was trying to run the script to start Karma. Here's test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

BASE_DIR=`dirname $0`

echo ""
echo "Starting Testacular Server (http://vojtajina.github.com/testacular)"
echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------"

testacular start $BASE_DIR/../config/testacular.conf.js $*
```

I run:

```
sh scripts/test.sh
```

The echos show up fine, and then I get the error:

```
scripts/test.sh: line 9: testacular: command not found
```

Comment: Karma was formerly known as Testacular so maybe change test.sh to call karma instead?

Comment: D'oh, can't believe I didn't think of that. Works fine now, thanks!

Comment: Cool I'll add an answer since it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Karma** was formerly known as **Testacular** so modify `test.sh` to call karma instead of testacular:

```
testacular start $BASE_DIR/../config/testacular.conf.js $*
```

change to this:

```
karma start $BASE_DIR/../config/testacular.conf.js $*
```

Comment: The source files for the Angular tutorials seem to be a bit outdated, thanks Gloopy!